# How to return error code 1 on error from PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

Can you give an example how to return error code 1 on error using PowerShell?

For example handling this situation:

```
if ($serviceUserName) {
  cmd /c $serviceBinaryFinalPath install -username:$serviceUserName -password:$serviceUserPassword -servicename:"$ServiceName" -displayname:"$serviceDisplayName" -description:"$serviceDescription"
} else {
  cmd /c $serviceBinaryFinalPath install --localsystem -servicename:"$ServiceName" -displayname:"$serviceDisplayName" -description:"$serviceDescription"
}
```

Comment: `try {bla-bla-bla} catch {exit 1}`

Comment: Why `cmd /c`? You don't need it.

Answer (score 10):

You're running external commands there, so you need to check the [automatic variable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/3.0/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/about/about_Automatic_Variables) `$LastExitCode` for detecting errors:

```
if ($LastExitCode -ne 0) {
  exit 1
}
```

Or just exit with the exit code of the last external command:

```
exit $LastExitCode
```

Note that some external commands (`robocopy` for instance) use exit codes not only for signaling errors, but also for providing non-error status information.

Comment: oh, I didn't even notice he isn't using powershell command :(